# Unable to checkout svn repository because of redirected cycles

Tags: svn

I was trying to checkout a repository using the following command :

svn checkout http://code.ascend4.org/ascend/branches/saheb-canvas/

I got the this error :
svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://code.ascend4.org/ascend/branches/saheb-canvas'

when i went inside the repository there was actually a link to the parent directory inside any sub-directory leading to the above error.

Please suggest a solution to this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong URL, `http://code.ascend4.org/ascend/branches/saheb-canvas/` is used for browsing.

As you can see in [their docs](http://ascend4.org/SvnInfo), you have to use this URL for SVN checkout:

```
svn co http://svn.ascend4.org/branches/saheb-canvas/
```